# vb6 MDI app - when mdi form maximized it goes underneath the status bottom bar issue

Tags: vb6, mdi

I am working on an old visual basic 6 app, which has just developed an issue, It never used to have.

It is an MDI form application, which has 1 main window which has a menu at the top and status bar at the bottom, along with 2 other status like bars. It also has around 50 Child windows to go within this master frame.

When the user maximizes any child window it seems the window maximizes but does not notice the toolbars at the bottom and it maximizes below them (out of view), so the bottom of the child window does not meet up with the top of the toolbars.

I have done 4 pictures which show it is design time, runtime normal and then maximized, as you can see it hides the buttons.

I have never seen this before

I have tried to code some resizing logic to counteract this in the child Private Sub Form_Resize() event, however, it has no effect at all.

Which leaves me to believe the window resizing when maximizing is dealt with via the windows system itself, or buried deep in vb, where I can not change it.

None of the controls have changed added/deleted on the forms, and I haven't changed any form/control values as far as I remember.

I have also tried bringing the controls to the front, then back etc, no impact

I have tried changing the zindex around in all ways, no impact

Has everyone ever seen this before or have any ideas

Thank You for reading, any help would be greatly appreciated

Thanks

[normal working not maxed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TnlJZ.png)

[maxxed screen showing issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gzhil.jpg)

[maxxed even with top menu closed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dTkEQ.png)

[design time vb6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oYLpX.png)

Comment: You can paste those images directly into your question.

Answer (score 2):

A pure VB6 solution for the child form:

```
Private Sub Form_Resize() 
  If WindowState <> vbMinimized then 
    Begin
      If WindowState = vbMaximized then
        WindowState = vbNormal
      Top = Me.Parent.Top + Me.Parent.TopToolbar.Height
      Height = Me.Parent.Height - Me.Parent.TopToolbar.Height - Me.Parent.BottomToolbar.Height
    End
```

The trick is not to allow maximized mode, and resize the window to fit the remaining space.

The title bar is still at the top of the MDI window, unlike the default maximize behavior.

It has been well over 10 years since I used VB6, please excuse any code imperfections.

Comment: it turns out, my issue was the fact I am using a 3rd codejock menu, which was overruling the standard vb6 mdi form actions, in the end, I have made hidden codejock toolbars underneath the vb6 standard ones and now the windows react as they should, however your answer would have been correct, if it was just a standard vb6 problems, so I vote for you as you did not know codejock was involved and couldn’t have

Answer (score -1):

I don't have a solution (yet), but I've been facing the same problem with an app of mine.  I believe that the issue is caused by the Win-7/Win-10 virtual desktop; the VB6 app thinks it's using the whole screen, but the task bar is on a separate virtual screen, which is on top.  I'll post in this thread if I get it solved...

Comment: do you by any chance use any Codejock controls on your project

Comment: No, mostly standard VB OCX's, with a couple of custom controls of my own (also developed in VB6).

Comment: it turns out, my issue was the fact I am using a 3rd codejock menu, which was overruling the standard vb6 mdi form actions, in the end, I have made hidden codejock toolbars underneath the vb6 standard ones and now the windows react as they should, maybe worth a try for yourself, if anything like that is in your project